# auto submit form to a url if textfield is not empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to auto submit a form when the username column is not  null. i've got my script down there but since i'm new to jquery, i've got it missed up and its not working

```
$(function() {
  var $username = $('#username'),
  if ($username != null){
  $("#form1").submit,function(event){

        event.preventDefault();
        data = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://mysample.com/ans.php",
        data: data,
        success: function(data) {
          $('#log_msg').html(data);
          var result = $.trim(data);
            if(result==="ok"){
             window.location = 'page.html';
            }
        });
  });
});
```

Comment: By not working, do you mean you get an error? If so, what error?

Comment: post the rest of the code please

Comment: The end of the `var` declaration needs to be a semicolon, not a comma. You should be getting a syntax error for that code.

Comment: @Jclasspill the script is messed up

Comment: You're running this code when the page is first loaded. How could the username be filled in before the user has had a chance do anything? You need to put it into an event handler.

Comment: @i_user http://www.w3schools.com/js/

Comment: Another syntax problem: After `$("#form1").submit` there should be a `(`, not `,`.

Comment: @Barmar i've have a script that saves the username for the first time. But now what i want to achieve is to auto submit for subsequent times the user comes to the page

Comment: @SimonStaton please explain what value that link provides to context of question? Just seems like unnecessary noise with no value

Comment: @charlietfl I think his point is that the code in the question has basic syntax errors in the Javascript. He needs to learn the language before we can help him with the logic.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use on change listener, like

```
$(document).on('change', '#input_id', function(e) {
    $('form_selector').submit();
});

$(document).on('submit', 'form_selector', function(e) {
//Your ajax submit logic
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do an AJAX submission, just call `$.ajax` in the `if`:

```
$(function() {
    var $username = $("#username").val();
    if ($username != '') {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/ans.php",
            data: $("#form1").serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
                $('#log_msg').html(data);
                var result = $.trim(data);
                if(result==="ok"){
                window.location = 'page.html';
            }
        });
    }
});
```

You don't need to define a `$("#form1").submit()` handler for this.

Comment: i follow your answer but when the textfield is not null i want it to auto submit a different form which is also have a textfield called username. that form is without action so i want to do that submission with ajax